# Google API keys - newer interface

Tags: android, google-maps

Prior to Maps v2, back in 2013, I had set up the Google Maps V1 API with two API keys,  one for debug and one for release the keys went in an .xml file, in the form:

```
android:apiKey="06oetc_etc_etc_etc_etc_w"
```

I know it was then necessary to have different strings for debug and release.

I have now migrated to Android Studio, a new machine and realise that I must use Maps V2 for mapping applications.

After this long lay off it appears that the web interface for getting an API key has changed and I am a bit confused. It looks like 15 months ago I did get an Android API key  starting  "Aiz... "and on the Google site's credentials tab I have two entries for my proposed project's package name, one for an application signed by the debug keystore and one for the app signed with my release keystore. I did no further work on this idea, as the PC I had was not up to the task. I now have a new machine.

The API key doesn't appear to be tied to the maps API, is this setup correct? I.e. the same key for both debug and release versions and the key not tied to the maps API at all?

I would like to know before starting the new project (which so far just has a reserved package name) in Android Studio.

All replies gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Consider use browser api key as an option.You can get it in developers console.
Also the fastest way to properly setup maps is to Right click project folde -> New -> Google ->Google Maps Activity

Comment: I have got a browser key and I use it for my GCM project. The key is sent from the server side in a .php file. It is not embedded in the Android code. My app is going to be on a phone, saying to Google "give me the map of where I am" - just like my existing V1 maps. Because this API is no longer supported, I can't look back to see what I did on a google site, The keys still work for V1 but you can't get a new one.